# VB.NET how to serialize JSON when returns 2 possible different formats

Tags: json, vb.net

I am working with this API that returns data in JSON format. I am trying to serialize the JSON into an object, but one of the elements comes in different formats. I have sent the company an example of the issue and they are "looking into it". I can't wait for them to get back I am trying to find a way around it. I was wondering if there is a way to create a Class to handle both formats without our creating two Classes to handle one element.

JSON Format 1

```
{
  "person": [
    {
      "Address": "PO Box 14079 Lexington KY 40512"
    }
  ]
}
```

JSON Format 2

```
{
  "person": [
    {
      "Address": {
        "City": "Lexington",
        "Line": "PO Box 14079",
        "State": "KY",
        "Zip": "40512"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my Class

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property Address As String
End Class
```

Is there a way to add an Address Class (like below) to my Person Class to handle both Address formats without creating an alternate Person Class?

```
Public Class Address
    Public Property City As String
    Public Property Line As String
    Public Property State As String
    Public Property Zip As String
End Class
```

Comment: Why not just a conversation that always returns either one or the other format? Or return both address formats and let the consumers choose?

Comment: Create separate classes for each structure and use the built-in serialization and deserialization.

Comment: i was trying to avoid creating two classes..,i thought there might be another way...